# picking the right Vgs th based on VOH and VOL

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet

My microcontroller has a VOH min of 2.4V and a VOL max of 0.4V.  How do I spec the right Vgs th for a transistor switch?

At first I thought, aim for the middle and go 1.5V.  But then I was thinking about needing to operate in saturation region and I'd be better off picking a lower Vgs th if I could.  Plenty of options at 0.7V and 1V.

Comment: Have you looked at the curves in the datasheet yet?

Comment: Also, pay attention to the conditions those output voltages are at, and realize that you won't be at those conditions very long if at all with a MOSFET.

Comment: More or less what Michael said BUT you probably are misreading the spec sheet. Odds are that Vol max is specified at some finite load value that is trying to pull it UP. It's likely that Vol_max in your case is ~~= 0.0 and you only need to worry about Voh_min which also is specified under load (pulling low and a gate drive is not usually too much of a challenge (except under capacitive transient). If in fact Vol_max_applicable ~= 0.0 look at the Vgs / Vds / Ids curve sets almost always provided for a FET Where (Voh_min_applicable - Vth_ gives you ample Ids & Vds in your application. ....

Comment: ... Usually Vth of about 1 V will be fine. Note that the curves are typical and not worst case and that they are usually given at several temperatures AND that some cross over at high Ids. Ask more if this is not enough or makes too little sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like from the description that you provided that you are intending to operate the MOSFET as a saturated switch. If this is the case and if the selection is for an N-Channel device then it is pretty easy to see that the MCU pin will have no trouble turning OFF the MOSFET. So the more important consideration becomes the available gate drive voltage to get the device turned on hard enough to satisfy your load switching requirements. You want to get the RDSon low enough that the part is not dissipating too much power at the load current that you need it to switch. You also want the low RDSon so the device will pull the load as close to GND as possible so the load gets the benefit to as much voltage across it as possible.